# Type safe Rails 3 Tableless Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) describes how to set up a tableless model in Rails 3 as in:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :content

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

It works quite well but what it doesn't do it let Rails know what types the attributes are. This means that while various plugins / libraries work, they tend to fall back to effectively seeing the attributes as an 'any' type. For example to_xml lists them as type 'yaml'.

Is there a way to tell Rails what the types of the attributes are in Tableless models?

Comment: I guess you could find some answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988410/attr-accessor-strongly-typed-ruby-on-rails. Similar question to yours.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [ActiveAttr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr), it provides typecasted attributes like this:

```
class Person
  include ActiveAttr::TypecastedAttributes
  attribute :age, :type => Integer
end
```

There is also a [RailsCast about ActiveAttr](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr).

Answer (score 0):

There is the [**activerecord-tableless**](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-tableless) gem. Its a gem to create tableless ActiveRecord models, so it has support for validations, associations, types.

The way you describe in the question does not support association nor (as you have discovered) types.