# Attribute accessor with a datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, attr-accessor

I am looking to set an attribute_accessor with a datatype associated with it like how we have fields in the model that have database that have datatypes like string , integer etc associated with them.

How do i tell rails that my attr_accessor should respond to a specific datatype. I am looking to set a datetime to one the accessor i am trying to create,

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom setter like

```
def field_name=(value)
  # check for type and dont assign it if its the wrong typ
  # or raise an error
end
```

just off of the top of my head

Also, duplicate question: [attr_accessor strongly typed Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988410/attr-accessor-strongly-typed-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: attr_accessible and attr_accessor are two VERY different things and attr_accessible has got nothing to do with the question asked above.